# Probability problem using the product rule?

Tags: probability

I try to solve the following probability problem, but can't seem to find the (proposed) solution...

> A music setup consists of a random selection of:
>
> - 1 tuner out of a set of which 50% is not working;
> - 1 amplifier out of a set of which 50% is not working;
> - 1 disk-player out of a set of which 25% is not working;
> - 2 speakers out of a set of which 33,33...% is not working;
>
> What is the probability music can be heard?

The proposed solution is $\frac{7}{18}$

I tried the following:

Applying the product rule $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2$

But then I realised the probality of the speakers changes after one working speaker is chosen. I guess the probalbilty would drop, but how much?

Could anyone give me some pointers? It doesn't seem like a difficult problem, but I guess I am missing something...

Comment: I feel like we need to know how many speakers there are in the collection to accurately answer this.

Comment: We do. I've found that when questions like this are set, we're expected to assume the set is infinitely large.

Comment: The size is not given in the problem statement... It's a problem at the end of a chapter regarding elementary probability + Bayes etc... But I don't see how conditional probability would help in this case.

Comment: Hint: *How many* speakers need to work for the music to be heard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have failure rates for the tuner, amplifier, disk player and two speakers.   (Assume these are drawn from a sufficiently large population.)

The key to this problem is in looking at how the music set needs to be hooked up.   That is: Whether the points of failure are linked together in series or in parallel.

Now, there are two possible sources, internal (disc) or external (radio).   Then the signal is passed from this source through the amplifier to the speakers.   How many speakers need to work for music to be heard?   How many of the sources?

So music can be heard if *either* the tuner *or* the disc player work, and *also* if the amplifier works, and *also* if *at least one* of the two speakers works.

Can you now find the probability that music can be heard?

Comment: Okay, I think I've got it. Is the following ok? If one of the speakers is working, music can be heard. Provided the sample is big enough at least one of the speakers is working with probability $2\cdot \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{8}{9}$. Same reasoning for the tuner and disk-player. At least one is working with probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{7}{8}$. Multiplying everything togheter with $\frac{1}{2}$ (amplifier) returns the proposed solution.
Interesting problem :)